# How to add animations on every re-render of component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, rendering

I have a simple component of my trivia-app on React. When I answer a question - my component re-renders the new question and I want to have an animation for the question block. But, I have only the one-time animation at the first render of this component. How to make animation on every re-render of the component?

Here is my sandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-ardinghelli-hn2zx?file=/src/App.js

And here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const questions = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
const answers = ["asgas", "asgasg", "ashash", "hasdha"];

export default function App() {
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="question">{questions[currentQuestion]}</h2>
      <div>
        {answers.map((i) => (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setCurrentQuestion((prevState) => prevState + 1);
            }}
            key={i}
          >
            {i}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.question {
  background-color: blue;
  animation: fromTop 0.5s linear;
}

@keyframes fromTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add something data to `<h2>`-tag, then React can re-render this tag and animation started.

`<h2 className="question" key={currentQuestion}>{questions[currentQuestion]}</h2>`

Comment: look, on my example in the topic it is working, but when I added it to this code
```<h2 key={questions[currentQuestion]} className={`${s.question} ${s.animated}`}
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: questions[currentQuestion].question}}/>```
It still not resetting animation, do you know any solutions in such case?

Comment: Can you provide the full code in sandbox? It hard to say looking at the small piece

Comment: Maybe, it not working beacause you resset the class name for `h2` tag. In CSS file you map the animation only for `question` class-name.

`className={`question ${s.question} ${s.animated}`}` -- try it.

Comment: Check it now https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-ardinghelli-hn2zx?file=/src/App.js
It is the same example as in my project

Comment: `<h2
        className="question"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: questions[currentQuestion]
        }}
        key={currentQuestion}
      />`

Worked fine. Notice: the changing inner HTML  by this way is not effect to re-render process.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I need to have quotes in my question and without it I can see only HTML-codes of quotes. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to add quotes (i still can't get it what the type of quotes you need), but for re-render just add `key` attribute that contained some dynamic value, so for each changes in this value React will re-render this tag.

Maybe you need insert data like this: `<h2 key={currentQuestion}>"{questions[currentQuestion}"</h2>` if you need `"`-quotes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `useEffect()`, because this will not animate as the component hasn't been "drawn" yet.

`useEffect` is executed after the render but before the "drawing" of the components, you have to use the hook `useLayoutEffect`. This hook executes after the drawing of the component, so you will have a lot more information about the layout like position, height, or weight.